# DRF json 404 insetad of html page

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I would like to replace default django 404 (and other in the future) with the DRF response, as easy as it is possible, just to return (standard DRF response):

```js
{
    "detail": "Not found."
}
```

So I put this code in my url.py file.

```js
from rest_framework.exceptions import NotFound
from django.conf.urls import handler404
handler404 = NotFound
```

When I set Debug flag (in the set Ture I'm geting 500, when set it to False 404 but in the html form.

I've read doc here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/ but to be honest I don't know how to put this into reality.

it seems to be easy, but somehow I failed to implement this (above code comes form the other SO threads).

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a custom view for the 404 then to use it.
for example:

in `views.py`:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseNotFound
import json

def error404(request, exception):
    response_data = {}
    response_data['detail'] = 'Not found.'
    return HttpResponseNotFound(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

then in `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import handler404

from yourapp.views import error404

handler404 = error404
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the quick replay, but behaviour is still the same ;(

Comment: btw. main urls.py  or the application one ?

Comment: @Piotr please check the last edit. I have tried to make it using the DRF's implemented exception but didn't work. Also I added `exception` parameter to the handler function to bind with handler404

Comment: Hello Peter, thank you it's working now :) ! Anyway does it mean we can't use restframework exception ? What is good in the standard exceptions that there are translations provided. I don't know why, but when I try to do: response_data['detail'] = _('Not found.') I'm getting 500 again :(

Comment: This works only on top `urls.py` file. To debug which file is the top you can here `.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py@resolve_error_handler`